# Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibrary' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#

I got a Silverlight 5 solution which contains the web project, the SL project and 3 other projects in the same solution.  The Web project references the 3 libraries.

Despite all the suggestions about the same subject I've not been able to solve this error yet.  I tried a lot of combinations.  Here's a list of what I tried

1) Deleted manually BIN and OBJ folder of all the projects in the solution

2) Clean Solution

3) Clean individual project

4) Changed the Compilation location from bin\x86\Debug to bin\ as suggested from 
some people

5) Tried x86 for all references

6) Tried Any CPU for all references

7) Tried a combination of x86 for libraries and Any CPU for Silverlight project and Web host

I'm out of ideas so that's why I'm seeking help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm well, strange enough I finally been able to make it work by choosing Release rather then Debug and making everything Any CPU.  The problem went away.